# Iframe resizer not resizing once site changed to ssl

Tags: iframe-resizer

I originally set this page up a few weeks ago, and it was working fine until the site went live and it was changed to ssl.

We've been in contact with the devs who made the page in the iframe, and got them to switch to ssl and made sure they have included the iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js file on their end.

I've also been running a test from one of my other sites to make sure everything was been set up properly on my end, and that worked no problems.

Link to page with iframe: https://www.bedsrus.co.nz/sleep-selector
My test page used to check my setup: https://www.bedsrus.co.nz/test

Logging has been left on, if you'd like to have a look.

I've tried changing the heightCalculationMethod to to some other options including lowestElement, bodyScroll, and max.

There are a few warnings coming from the content page but I don't think they would be causing the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure this one out.

The containing doc had the html and body elements set with height: 100%.
This was confusing the iframe resizer as some of the elements in the body were floating.

Setting the containing documents html and body elements to height: auto fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look and on https://www.bedsrus.co.nz/sleep-selector your using v1.4.4, where as the iframe is running the latest version of the script (v2.8.6)

Whilst this does work, you need the latest version on the both pages to use all the features of the current version.

The script isn't logging to the console on your test page.